# Set value ASP.NET_SessionId (document.cookie DOM) (IE 7)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vba, cookies, internet-explorer-7

is there a way to change the value of the HTTPOnly cookie ASP.NET_SessionId? I need to do it with JavaScript or Access-VBA, since I don't have access to an ASP.NET server. Also, it needs to be done on Internet Explorer 7.

Here's the cenario:

An ASP.NET application sets this cookie at login time. I need to change the value after it. If there's a way...

Comment: If you know the name of the cookie and have access to the DOM document (which you can get using js or VBA) then you should be able to change the cookie value. What have you tried so far?  And why do you need to do this?

Comment: I need to do this because I call another application while navigating through the site. This application generates another cookie, which is different than mine, invalidating my solution. So, I need to change the old value to the new one.

Comment: I've tried to use the document.cookie method of javascript, VBA function IE.Navigate by setting the Header, the simple setcookie from javascript, with the same luck as the others. The thing is that this cookie seems to be special, since by no means I'm able, by the methods I tried, to set a value to this.

Comment: Sorry - I skipped over the http only part: now that I've read up on that, it seems like you're out of luck...  Time for a new approach?

Answer (score 1):

A HTTPOnly cookie is just that, HTTP only.  It is set that way so you can't change it or access it via JavaScript.

[Protecting Your Cookies: HttpOnly](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/08/protecting-your-cookies-httponly.html)